# View stdout/stderr of systemd service

Tags: logs, io-redirection, systemd

I have created a simple systemd service file for a custom application. The application works well when I run it manually, but my CPU gets maxed out when I run it with systemd.

I'm trying do track down where my problem is, but I don't know where to find the output (or how to configure systemd to put the output somewhere).

Here is my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Syncs files with a server when they change
Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/filesync-client --port 2500
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/filesync-client
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Throughout the application, I output to stdout and stderr.

How can I read the output of my daemon?

Edit:

I found `man systemd.exec`, which mentioned the `StandardOutput=` option, but I'm not sure how to use it.  From the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/wheezy/systemd/systemd.exec.5.en.html):

> *`StandardOutput=`*
>
> Controls where file descriptor 1 (STDOUT) of the executed processes is connected to. Takes one of **inherit**, **null**, **tty**, **syslog**, **kmsg**, **kmsg+console**, **syslog+console** or **socket**.
>
> If set to **inherit** the file descriptor of standard input is duplicated for standard output. If set to **null** standard output will be connected to `/dev/null`, i.e. everything written to it will be lost. If set to **tty** standard output will be connected to a tty (as configured via *`TTYPath=`*, see below). If the TTY is used for output only the executed process will not become the controlling process of the terminal, and will not fail or wait for other processes to release the terminal.  **syslog** connects standard output to the syslog(3) system logger.  **kmsg** connects it with the kernel log buffer which is accessible via dmesg(1).  **syslog+console** and **kmsg+console** work similarly but copy the output to the system console as well.  **socket** connects standard output to a socket from socket activation, semantics are similar to the respective option of *`StandardInput=`*. This setting defaults to inherit.

Does this mean that these are my only options?  I would like, for example, to put output in `/dev/shm` or something. I suppose I could use a Unix domain socket and write a simple listener, but this seems a little unnecessary.

I just need this for debugging, and I'll probably end up removing most of the logs and change the output to syslog.

Comment: Have you tried checking `/var/log/syslog` for output? Most systems will log stuff into `/var/log/` so I'd start by checking there. You can use `grep` to search for text if you know the output: `grep "my output" /var/log` should do the trick.

Comment: @sbtkd85 - Well, I don't have `/var/log/syslog`, but `/var/log/messages` does the trick. The problem is, according to the logs, my daemon crashes on start, yet I can tell that it is still running because it has an HTTP server, and I can query it. It seems the rest of the logs are getting lost...

Comment: Why not try setting `StandardOutput=tty` so you can see what is happening when you launch your daemon. It should output the terminal (you may have to use `ttyS0` or similar to get the output on your screen).

Comment: Shouldn't standard IO redirection operators work in this context. Something like `ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/filesync-client --port 2500 2>/tmp/filesync.log`

Comment: What is actually abusing your CPU? Is it systemd, your service or system (e.g. by spawning new copies of the service because systemd went crazy)?

Comment: @peterph - It was a problem with my service, which is why I wanted to look at the output. The problem is now solved though.

Comment: Appears that it is possible now with newer versions of systemd, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48052152/32453

Answer (score 308, accepted):

#### Update

As mikemaccana notes, the [systemd journal](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/journalctl.html) is now the standard logging device for most distros. 
To view the `stdout` and `stderr` of a systemd unit use the [`journalctl` command.](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html)

```
sudo journalctl -u [unit]
```

**Original Answer**

By default `stdout` and `stderr` of a systemd unit are sent to syslog.

If you're using the full systemd, this will be accesible via `journalctl`.
On Fedora, it should be `/var/log/messages` but syslog will put it where your rules say.

Due to the date of the post, and assuming most people that are exposed to systemd are via fedora, you were probably hit by the bug described here:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=754938
It has a good explanation of how it all works too =) (This was a bug in selinux-policy that caused error messages to not be logged, and was fixed in `selinux-policy-3.10.0-58.fc16`)

Comment: Note that using the standard logging mechanism like this will *not* create persistent logs by default. To do that, you'll need to create /var/log/journal, and then run `sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald`

Comment: what syslog facility and priority?

Comment: This worked for me: `StandardOutput=syslog+console` and `StandardError=syslog+console` after that all output from my unit appeared in journalctl.  The default setting was wrong apparently. (Such as DefaultStandardOutput in /etc/systemd/system.conf)

Comment: @gregn3 That does not help for me. It just keeps outputting stderr, no matter what I do :(

Comment: @Joakim I have no idea right now... (but I would first check that the issue is not with the unit itself, that it works correctly when started from the command line (as a normal script)... then I would check systemd and journalctl settings... good luck :) )

Comment: `-f` was helpful for me.  Followed the log as changes occur (use case was following minecraft server which was running as a daemon)

Comment: This is driving me crazy... On a standard Debian stretch journalctl won't show me any of the standard output whatsoever. I even use `/usr/bin/stdbuf -oL <cmd>` and an explicit `StandardOutput=journal`. Still nothing.

Comment: use `sudo journalctl -eu [unit]` to go the end of the logging

Comment: I'm very confused, on OpenSUSE Leap 15.2 journalctl -u example.service does not show the stdout at all. It shows the times when the service was started and stopped but no stdout or stderr.

Comment: "Note that using the standard logging mechanism like this will not create persistent logs by default" what is does this means?

Comment: @Viren: It's clear what it means (logs disappear on reboot) but is it right or not?

Answer (score 127):

Shorter, simpler, non-legacy answer:

```
sudo journalctl -u [unitfile]
```

Where [unitfile] is the systemd `.service` name. Eg, to see messages from `myapp.service`,

```
sudo journalctl --unit=myapp
```

To follow logs in real time:

```
sudo journalctl -f -u myapp
```

Comment: Note that you might have to `sudo` if you get a `No journal files found` error.

Comment: syslog is not legacy...

Comment: It is in current Linux distros. You might really like syslog but that doesn't change what they ship with.

Comment: So Ubuntu 16.04 LTS isn't a current distro in 2017? Maybe you're conflating the idea of sysvinit with syslog.

Comment: @JECompton Ubuntu 16.04 also uses journald.

Comment: Sure. And it also uses syslog. My point was not that systemd is not used, but that syslog is not legacy.

Comment: @JECompton if all logging on current Linux distros uses journald, and syslog is not necessary and only used for compatibility, then it logically follows that syslog is legacy.