# How to direct the journal output of certain units to a particular file?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, logs, systemd-journald

I've got a system with several daemons running (as systemd units) that output log information to the journal in Arch Linux. I want to direct the journal output of some of those unit files into a separate text file whose location I specify, essentially creating a log file for a subset of units. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468444/ .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATE:** For newer systemd versions (since systemd 236) this is actually possible. See [systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Logging%20and%20Standard%20Input/Output) for [StandardOutput](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=) and [StandardError](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardError=) stanzas. Those support the following options, as an excerpt:

> The **file:path** option may be used to connect a specific file system
> object to standard output. The semantics are similar to the same
> option of StandardInput=, see above. If path refers to a regular file
> on the filesystem, it is opened (created if it doesn't exist yet) for
> writing at the beginning of the file, but without truncating it. If
> standard input and output are directed to the same file path, it is
> opened only once, for reading as well as writing and duplicated. This
> is particularly useful when the specified path refers to an AF_UNIX
> socket in the file system, as in that case only a single stream
> connection is created for both input and output.
>
> **append:path** is similar to file:path above, but it opens the file in append mode.
>
> **truncate:path** is similar to file:path above, but it truncates the file when opening it. For units with multiple command lines, e.g.
> Type=oneshot services with multiple ExecStart=, or services with
> ExecCondition=, ExecStartPre= or ExecStartPost=, the output file is
> reopened and therefore re-truncated for each command line. If the
> output file is truncated while another process still has the file
> open, e.g. by an ExecReload= running concurrently with an ExecStart=,
> and the other process continues writing to the file without adjusting
> its offset, then the space between the file pointers of the two
> processes may be filled with NUL bytes, producing a sparse file. Thus,
> truncate:path is typically only useful for units where only one
> process runs at a time, such as services with a single ExecStart= and
> no ExecStartPost=, ExecReload=, ExecStop= or similar.
>
> [...]
>
> The **fd:name** option connects standard output to a specific, named file descriptor provided by a socket unit. A name may be specified as part
> of this option, following a ":" character (e.g. "fd:foobar"). If no
> name is specified, the name "stdout" is implied (i.e. "fd" is
> equivalent to "fd:stdout"). At least one socket unit defining the
> specified name must be provided via the Sockets= option, and the file
> descriptor name may differ from the name of its containing socket
> unit. If multiple matches are found, the first one will be used. See
> FileDescriptorName= in systemd.socket(5) for more details about named
> descriptors and their ordering.

**Original answer:**

Seems this is not possible and unwanted by upstream (redirecting stdout/stderr to individual files) see e.g. http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2012-March/004705.html - read the whole thread for more context information how this is intended to work.

What you can do, is either log to syslog, and that way write to individual files. Or the other way around, if the unit calls some program which can write a log itself, then use that to log to a file.

You may also want to take a look at [View stdout/stderr of systemd service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20399/view-stdout-stderr-of-systemd-service)

What you already can do with your current setup, is use
`journalctl -u yourunitname > yourlogfile_for_yourunitname`
to direct the whole journal output for your unit "yourunitname" into a file.

On the latter part, you should also take a look at the hints from Lennart from abovementioned mailing list thread:

> On recent systemd versions something like `systemd-journalctl -o cat _SYSTEMD_UNIT=postgresql.service` should create a very simple output
> that only includes the actual messages and nothing else. You can even
> pass "-f" and make this live."

**EDIT:**
Actually, for newer systemd versions the command is only **journalctl** and from what I can tell, the abovementioned long command is the same as `journalctl -u yourunitname` and you can also `-f` there to "follow" the output (as in tailf or tail -f).