# Where does stdout and stderr go in the background

Tags: terminal, systemd, background-process, stdout, stderr

When processes get executed in the background, for example by using `systemd` to start the processes at startup, why doesn't the `stdout` and `stderr` still appear on the terminal when we access the terminal via SSH or serial? Where does it go exactly?

I understand that if we directly run a process from the terminal, that that process will become a child process of the terminal instance and hence, `stdout` and `stderr` will write to a file descriptor understood by the terminal.

However it's not understood where the `stdout` and `stderr` is going when a process is executed in the background not from the terminal. Thanks in advance .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View stdout/stderr of systemd service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20399/view-stdout-stderr-of-systemd-service)

Comment: stdout and stderr are file descriptors 1 and 2, respectively. A process inherits the file descriptors from its parent. Whatever the parent uses as stdout and stderr, the child uses as well. Of course, the child has full control - it can close stdout and stderr and open other files. For example, the child may detect it's running in the background and decide to write its messages to /var/log/myownlogfile. In short, there is no general answer to your question; it depends on parent and child.

Comment: “that process will become a child process of the terminal instance” — no, it’s a child of the shell, and uses whatever file descriptors the shell gives it.

Comment: @berndbausch “Whatever the parent uses as stdout and stderr, the child uses as well” not necessarily, the child uses whatever the parent *gives it* by default (*e.g.* with redirections, the shell doesn’t pass its own descriptors to the child, it passes the result of the redirection).

Comment: @StephenKitt Let me see if I understand it correctly. The shell forks, creating a child identical to itself. That child gets the parent's FD's, which it might then redirect using a combination of `open`, `close` and `dup` system calls. So, in my understanding it's the child that inherits the parent's files and redirects them. Of course, at this point in time, the child is still a shell, and only after redirection will it `exec` the program. Perhaps we are both right.

Comment: @berndbausch yes, you’re right; in context of this question I reckon the situation after `exec` is more relevant than that between `fork` and `exec`.